# How to +1 on a date in select Laravel

Tags: laravel

How do I add +1 on select? I need this for full calendar:

**I use this but I am still getting an error:**

```
$date= Date::select('name','start','end'+1)->get();
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            events : [

                @foreach($date as $task)
                {
                    title : '{{ $task->name }}',
                    start : '{{ $task->start}}',
                    end : '{{ $task->end}}',
                },
                @endforeach
            ]
        })
    });
</script>
```

If i not +1 it shows a day before date in database, and if i use +1 it is an Unknown column

Comment: which type has the field you want to increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using MySQL to add one day.. Because when you say `'end' + 1` it is like trying to make a concatenation which won't work in PHP as `.` is used for concatenating but your expectation is I assume to add 1 day to a date. So try this:

```
$date= Date::select('name', 'start', \DB::raw('date_add(end, interval 1 day) as end'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to perform an action like **+1 day**.

```
@foreach($date as $task)
{
    title : '{{ $task->name }}',
    start : '{{ $task->start }}',
    end : '{{ Carbon::parse($task->end)->addDays(1) }}',
},
@endforeach
```

You will need `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of your class.